# Wireless Security System deadbolts with door handle that locks - how to disable door locks

Tags: lock

We installed a wireless security system to eliminate keys for entry into the home.  This works well for the dead bolt, but the door handle has the lever on the inside to turn and lock.  To enter, you have to have a key.  What is the best solution without tearing up the door handle lock for future owners?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply leave it, and not use that lock.  That way if your wireless deadbolt breaks, or you need some extra privacy, you can still lock the house.

Failing that, just shove something in the hole in the frame so you cant engage the lock.  Easy to reverse if needed.

Comment: There's alot to be said for"just don't lock it" -- least effort easiest reversal. If you're worried that guests migh be "helpful",  duct tape over the inner control is a simple "don't touch" indicator. Not elegant, but...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to go out and buy a non-locking handleset -- since you are't using it for security, the only concern is that it have a good weather-resistant finish, so it should be cheap(ish).

The existing handleset *could* be modified not to be lockable -- I've done it -- but I have a bit of trouble recommending that for the average individual when replacement is so affordable.